# How to change the color of icon font using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a theme from ThemeForest that is utilizing icon fonts. In the css files I see a @font-face to import the fonts and a list of all the icons as such:

```
.socials li.social-lastfm a:before,
.socials li.social-soundcloud a:before {
   font-family: 'icomoon-essential';
   speak: none;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 1;
   color: green;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

In this example there are several more icons, however of all the icons that I have on the theme only one of them turns green. I have added new rules to this css including .socials li.social-twitter a:before etc..

Even with the addition of rules, the color of the icons are not changing. As I am using WordPress, I went into the backend in order to determine if I could change the icons through some sort of plugin. To my demise, I cannot find a solution.

If you know of a way that I could fix the problem please let me know.

Comment: What theme are you using, maybe there is a demo version that allows us to see it live?

Comment: The icons are just a custom font, so the CSS above will correctly set the `color` to green. If it's not displaying as you expect, perhaps you have some styling elsewhere that's overriding this. Try and narrow it down so that you can create an example in something like jsFiddle that shows the simplest version of the problem.

Comment: Did you try something like color: red; instead of color: green;?

Comment: You may need to create a new font. This link might help you http://benfrain.com/make-a-custom-resolution-independent-icon-font-in-four-minutes-perfect-for-retinahd/

Comment: @PhilippBraun - the whole point of an icon font is that you can apply all the styling you can to any other text. You can control the color, size, text-shadow etc. using a single font.

Comment: You should look for info about using dev-tools. Any browser has one, and using them you can see why the color that you are specifying is not beeing applied. (CherryFlavourPez is right, color: green should work, your problem comes from elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you could post your html code here too so we can figure out what's the problem is. Supposely the html code is like below:

```
<ul class='socials'>
    <li class='social-lastfm'><a href='#'>Icon A</a></li>
    <li class='social-soundcloud'><a href='#'>Icon B</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use !important to rewrite previous css.